# Implementing attributes to pre-built table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I'm using a piece of software which automatically generates a table containing data and I'm trying to add some expand/collapse functionality in addition to this. I can't change how the table is created within the software, so the option I'm attempting is to add specific class names and attributes with jQuery.

I'm trying to re-create the layout that the following plugin uses: [Alvaro's Collapsable Table Plugin for jQuery](http://alvaroveliz.github.io/aCollapTable/), however this may not be the best way to do it.

This is the table that the software generates:

```html
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='http://alvaroveliz.github.io/aCollapTable/stylesheets/app.css' />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://alvaroveliz.github.io/aCollapTable/javascripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://alvaroveliz.github.io/aCollapTable/javascripts/jquery.aCollapTable.js"></script>
    
    <table style="border-collapse:collapse;" class="ls" LID="exampleRS" cellpadding="0">
   <tr>
      <td class="cRS10 lt" cid="0" uid="10" name="cRS10" type="columnTitle"><span tabIndex="0" class="textItem" ctx="1">Header</span></td>
      <td class="cRS12 lt" cid="1" uid="12" name="cRS12" type="columnTitle"><span tabIndex="-1" class="textItem" ctx="2">Value</span></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td class="cRS15 oh" cid="0" uid="15" name="cRS15" type="section"><span tabIndex="-1" class="textItem" ctx="3">Parent1</span></td>
      <td style="text-align:right" class="cRS17 oh" cid="1" uid="17" name="cRS17" type="section"><span tabIndex="-1" class="textItem" ctx="4:3">123</span></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td class="cRS20 lc" cid="0" uid="20" name="cRS20" type="datavalue"><span tabIndex="-1" class="textItem" ctx="5:6:3">Element2</span></td>
      <td style="text-align:right" class="cRS22 lm" cid="1" uid="22" name="cRS22" type="datavalue"><span tabIndex="-1" class="textItem" ctx="6:5:3">123</span></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td class="cRS20 lc" cid="0" uid="20" name="cRS20" type="datavalue"><span tabIndex="-1" class="textItem" ctx="7:8:3">Element3</span></td>
      <td style="text-align:right" class="cRS22 lm" cid="1" uid="22" name="cRS22" type="datavalue"><span tabIndex="-1" class="textItem" ctx="8:7:3">123</span></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

I manually updated table to replicate the table from Alvaro's example:

```html
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='http://alvaroveliz.github.io/aCollapTable/stylesheets/app.css' />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://alvaroveliz.github.io/aCollapTable/javascripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://alvaroveliz.github.io/aCollapTable/javascripts/jquery.aCollapTable.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.collaptable').aCollapTable({ 
          startCollapsed: true, 
          addColumn: false,
          plusButton: '<span class="icon-plus-circle"></span>', 
          minusButton: '<span class="icon-minus-circle"></span>' 
        });
      });
    </script>


<table style="border-collapse:collapse;" class="ls collaptable table" LID="exampleRS" cellpadding="0">
   <tr>
      <td class="cRS10 lt" cid="0" uid="10" name="cRS10" type="columnTitle"><span tabIndex="0" class="textItem" ctx="1">Header</span></td>
      <td class="cRS12 lt" cid="1" uid="12" name="cRS12" type="columnTitle"><span tabIndex="-1" class="textItem" ctx="2">Value</span></td>
   </tr>
   <tr data-id="1" data-parent="">
      <td class="cRS15 oh" cid="0" uid="15" name="cRS15" type="section"><span tabIndex="-1" class="textItem" ctx="3">Parent1</span></td>
      <td style="text-align:right" class="cRS17 oh" cid="1" uid="17" name="cRS17" type="section"><span tabIndex="-1" class="textItem" ctx="4:3">123</span></td>
   </tr>
   <tr data-id="2" data-parent="1">
      <td class="cRS20 lc" cid="0" uid="20" name="cRS20" type="datavalue"><span tabIndex="-1" class="textItem" ctx="5:6:3">Element2</span></td>
      <td style="text-align:right" class="cRS22 lm" cid="1" uid="22" name="cRS22" type="datavalue"><span tabIndex="-1" class="textItem" ctx="6:5:3">123</span></td>
   </tr>
   <tr data-id="3" data-parent="1">
      <td class="cRS20 lc" cid="0" uid="20" name="cRS20" type="datavalue"><span tabIndex="-1" class="textItem" ctx="7:8:3">Element3</span></td>
      <td style="text-align:right" class="cRS22 lm" cid="1" uid="22" name="cRS22" type="datavalue"><span tabIndex="-1" class="textItem" ctx="8:7:3">123</span></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

From the original table, the only way I think I can identify the  tags to add the classes 'data-id' and 'data-parent' to, is by accessing the child  tag and of it contains 'oh' then it's a parent row, and if it contains 'lc' then it's a child row.

As a starting point, I've tried to loop over every 'tr' within the table and assign 'data-id', and then assign every 'tr' with a 'td' class of 'lc' to a 'data-parent'. This is what I've tried but I'm falling short.

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' href='http://alvaroveliz.github.io/aCollapTable/stylesheets/app.css' />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://alvaroveliz.github.io/aCollapTable/javascripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://alvaroveliz.github.io/aCollapTable/javascripts/jquery.aCollapTable.js"></script>
    
    <script>
    
    $(document).ready(function(){
 
 $("[lid='exampleRS'] tr").each(function(){
  $(this).attr("data-id", $(this).index());
 });

 $("[lid='exampleRS'] td.lc").each(function(){
  $(this).closest('tr').attr("data-parent", $(this).closest('tr').find('.data-id').text());
 });

});

</script>
    
    <table style="border-collapse:collapse;" class="ls" LID="exampleRS" cellpadding="0">
   <tr>
      <td class="cRS10 lt" cid="0" uid="10" name="cRS10" type="columnTitle"><span tabIndex="0" class="textItem" ctx="1">Header</span></td>
      <td class="cRS12 lt" cid="1" uid="12" name="cRS12" type="columnTitle"><span tabIndex="-1" class="textItem" ctx="2">Value</span></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td class="cRS15 oh" cid="0" uid="15" name="cRS15" type="section"><span tabIndex="-1" class="textItem" ctx="3">Parent1</span></td>
      <td style="text-align:right" class="cRS17 oh" cid="1" uid="17" name="cRS17" type="section"><span tabIndex="-1" class="textItem" ctx="4:3">123</span></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td class="cRS20 lc" cid="0" uid="20" name="cRS20" type="datavalue"><span tabIndex="-1" class="textItem" ctx="5:6:3">Element2</span></td>
      <td style="text-align:right" class="cRS22 lm" cid="1" uid="22" name="cRS22" type="datavalue"><span tabIndex="-1" class="textItem" ctx="6:5:3">123</span></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td class="cRS20 lc" cid="0" uid="20" name="cRS20" type="datavalue"><span tabIndex="-1" class="textItem" ctx="7:8:3">Element3</span></td>
      <td style="text-align:right" class="cRS22 lm" cid="1" uid="22" name="cRS22" type="datavalue"><span tabIndex="-1" class="textItem" ctx="8:7:3">123</span></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Any assistance with moving forward and next steps would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working example:

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' href='http://alvaroveliz.github.io/aCollapTable/stylesheets/app.css' />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://alvaroveliz.github.io/aCollapTable/javascripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://alvaroveliz.github.io/aCollapTable/javascripts/jquery.aCollapTable.js"></script>
    
<script>
    
     $(document).ready(function() {
        var lastParentId = 0;
        $("[lid='exampleRS'] tr").each(function() {
            var index=$(this).index();
            if(index==0) return;
            $(this).attr("data-id", index);
            $(this).attr("data-parent", "");
            if ($(this).find(".lc").length > 0) {
                $(this).attr("data-parent", lastParentId);
            } else {
                lastParentId = $(this).index();

            }
        });
        $("[lid='exampleRS']").addClass("collaptable");
        $('.collaptable').aCollapTable({
            startCollapsed: true,
            addColumn: false,
            plusButton: '<span class="icon-plus-circle"></span>',
            minusButton: '<span class="icon-minus-circle"></span>'
        });
    });

</script>
    
    <table style="border-collapse:collapse;" class="ls" LID="exampleRS" cellpadding="0">
   <tr>
      <td class="cRS10 lt" cid="0" uid="10" name="cRS10" type="columnTitle"><span tabIndex="0" class="textItem" ctx="1">Header</span></td>
      <td class="cRS12 lt" cid="1" uid="12" name="cRS12" type="columnTitle"><span tabIndex="-1" class="textItem" ctx="2">Value</span></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td class="cRS15 oh" cid="0" uid="15" name="cRS15" type="section"><span tabIndex="-1" class="textItem" ctx="3">Parent1</span></td>
      <td style="text-align:right" class="cRS17 oh" cid="1" uid="17" name="cRS17" type="section"><span tabIndex="-1" class="textItem" ctx="4:3">123</span></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td class="cRS20 lc" cid="0" uid="20" name="cRS20" type="datavalue"><span tabIndex="-1" class="textItem" ctx="5:6:3">Element2</span></td>
      <td style="text-align:right" class="cRS22 lm" cid="1" uid="22" name="cRS22" type="datavalue"><span tabIndex="-1" class="textItem" ctx="6:5:3">123</span></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td class="cRS20 lc" cid="0" uid="20" name="cRS20" type="datavalue"><span tabIndex="-1" class="textItem" ctx="7:8:3">Element3</span></td>
      <td style="text-align:right" class="cRS22 lm" cid="1" uid="22" name="cRS22" type="datavalue"><span tabIndex="-1" class="textItem" ctx="8:7:3">123</span></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: That's brilliant, thanks :). How would I go about adjusting this for hierarchies underneath each parent? Manual mock up to create desired effect: https://jsfiddle.net/nusy2ay2/

Answer (score 1):

You tagged your question with [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript), hence a `non-`[jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) answer:

1. Iterate your rows
2. Check if the `td` carry a class of `oh`. If yes, apply the header class and `data-` attributes by using an incremented counter. Increment the `parent` counter.
3. Check if the `td` carry a class of `lc`. If yes, apply the child class and `data-` attributes by using the incremented counter as well as the incremented `parent` counter. Do not increment the `parent` counter.

Here is an attempt:

```js
var rows = document.querySelectorAll('table[LID="exampleRS"] tr'), 
 cols, data = 0, parent = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) { 

  // Search td with a class of oh
  cols = rows[i].querySelectorAll('td.oh');
  if (cols.length > 0) { // if found..
   parent = data; // increment the parent counter
 rows[i].setAttribute('data-id', ++data); // set the data-id attibute incrementally
 rows[i].setAttribute('data-parent', ''); // reset the data-parent attribute
 rows[i].classList.add('parent'); // add class to show it as parent
  } 
  
  // Search td with a class of lc
  cols = rows[i].querySelectorAll('td.lc');
  if (cols.length > 0) { // if found...
 rows[i].setAttribute('data-id', ++data); // set the data-id attibute incrementally
 rows[i].setAttribute('data-parent', parent); // set the data-parent attibute 
 rows[i].classList.add('child'); // add class to show it as parent
  }
}
```

```css
.parent { font-weight: bold; }
.child { font-style: italic; }
```

```html
<table style="border-collapse:collapse;" class="ls" LID="exampleRS" cellpadding="0">
   <tr>
      <td class="cRS10 lt" cid="0" uid="10" name="cRS10" type="columnTitle"><span tabIndex="0" class="textItem" ctx="1">Header</span></td>
      <td class="cRS12 lt" cid="1" uid="12" name="cRS12" type="columnTitle"><span tabIndex="-1" class="textItem" ctx="2">Value</span></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td class="cRS15 oh" cid="0" uid="15" name="cRS15" type="section"><span tabIndex="-1" class="textItem" ctx="3">Parent1</span></td>
      <td style="text-align:right" class="cRS17 oh" cid="1" uid="17" name="cRS17" type="section"><span tabIndex="-1" class="textItem" ctx="4:3">123</span></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td class="cRS20 lc" cid="0" uid="20" name="cRS20" type="datavalue"><span tabIndex="-1" class="textItem" ctx="5:6:3">Element2</span></td>
      <td style="text-align:right" class="cRS22 lm" cid="1" uid="22" name="cRS22" type="datavalue"><span tabIndex="-1" class="textItem" ctx="6:5:3">123</span></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td class="cRS20 lc" cid="0" uid="20" name="cRS20" type="datavalue"><span tabIndex="-1" class="textItem" ctx="7:8:3">Element3</span></td>
      <td style="text-align:right" class="cRS22 lm" cid="1" uid="22" name="cRS22" type="datavalue"><span tabIndex="-1" class="textItem" ctx="8:7:3">123</span></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td class="cRS15 oh" cid="0" uid="15" name="cRS15" type="section"><span tabIndex="-1" class="textItem" ctx="3">Parent1</span></td>
      <td style="text-align:right" class="cRS17 oh" cid="1" uid="17" name="cRS17" type="section"><span tabIndex="-1" class="textItem" ctx="4:3">123</span></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td class="cRS20 lc" cid="0" uid="20" name="cRS20" type="datavalue"><span tabIndex="-1" class="textItem" ctx="5:6:3">Element2</span></td>
      <td style="text-align:right" class="cRS22 lm" cid="1" uid="22" name="cRS22" type="datavalue"><span tabIndex="-1" class="textItem" ctx="6:5:3">123</span></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td class="cRS20 lc" cid="0" uid="20" name="cRS20" type="datavalue"><span tabIndex="-1" class="textItem" ctx="7:8:3">Element3</span></td>
      <td style="text-align:right" class="cRS22 lm" cid="1" uid="22" name="cRS22" type="datavalue"><span tabIndex="-1" class="textItem" ctx="8:7:3">123</span></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```